# Sitecore Solr Index Configuration Set different root path

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore7

I need add to single Solr index 2 different sitecore path */sitecore/content/System/My Path* and */sitecore/content/System/My Path 2*.

How I can do it in correct way ?

Should I just add new **crawler** description to locations section with new root value. Should I use **|** spliter at root section ? Or need I copy all **index** section with new path in root ?

```xml
<index id="my_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="core">myindex</param>
    <param desc="rebuildcore">myindex_swap</param>
    <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
    <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/countryIndexConfiguration" />
    <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
        <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/manual" />
    </strategies>
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/System/My Path</Root>
        </crawler>                          
    </locations>
</index>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy `crawler` and use different tag name than the original one, e.g. `crawler1`. It doesn't matter what's the tag name, so you can use some more specific tag names, e.g. `news` or `blogs`. The important thing is that you can not have 2 tags with the same name under `locations` tag.

Sample config with 2 roots:

```xml
<locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
    <news type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <Database>web</Database>
        <Root>/sitecore/content/System/news</Root>
    </news>                          
    <blogs type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <Database>web</Database>
        <Root>/sitecore/content/System/blogs</Root>
    </blogs>                          
</locations>
```

Answer (score 1):

We are using multiple tags with same name as crawler under locations and its working fine. It supports multiple tags with same name.